# Does ag-grid-angular version 23+ require Angular 9?

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid with Angular 8.  When updating `ag-grid-angular` from version 22.1.1 to 23.1.1, I encountered an unexpected peer dependency error:

```
> npm install
npm WARN ag-grid-angular@23.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ag-grid-angular@23.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
...
```

So `ag-grid-angular` is now requiring Angular 9.  I was expecting it to continue to work with Angular 8.

The [angular-grid homepage](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/) states, "Version 23 onwards of `ag-grid-angular` / `@ag-grid-community/angular` will support Angular 6+ only."

However, as of ag-grid-angular version 23.0.0, the Angular dependencies were [updated](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/commit/ff804acd1e4c6bfb7eeb5f4d08e96300375cbba9#diff-1d05a9c9c5a73b877ba6df56c6908a85) from "^4.0.0" to "~9.0.0".  This despite the comment on the relevant change (see AG-3802 in the [ag-grid-changelog](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/)) that states "Angular 6+ is now the minimum supported version Angular."

Is this an undocumented feature, a bug, or (most likely) a misunderstanding by me?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/) and scroll to the end where there's the version table. You need Angular 7-9 for ag-grid 23

Comment: Thanks for the link, @karimaounn.  That version table adds to my conviction that I should be able to use Angular 8 with ag-grid 23 (which is inconsistent with the observed behavior that ag-grid 23 declares a dependency on Angular 9+).  I'm still not sure whether this is an implementation bug or a documentation bug, however.